# ido-enabled find-file does not match an existing file name when I yank file name and directory

Tags: ido, ido-find-file

I enabled IDO mode in my emacs (version 25.2.1, Linux) and now I am trying to open a file.

I am in the directory `~/foo` .
The file is `~/foo/baz/bar.cpp` and it does exist.

I have `baz/bar.cpp` in my kill ring.

I press `C-x C-f` , followed by `C-y`.

The minibuffer shows

```
Find file: ~/foo/baz/bar.cpp<caret>[No Match]
```

At this point, if I press (C-f), my "normal" `find-file` locates the file just fine.

But, why is IDO giving me "No Match"?

*More information:*

Yanking just the file name (no directory) works fine.

Pressing "Enter" when "No Match" is show leads to another find-file minbuffer, not to a new file creation.